# Pycharm conda env not showing packages installed via pip

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

Running Pycharm, using Anaconda, with a `conda` env running Python 2.7 on OS X.

In terminal, running `conda list` shows package list as being installed... but it doesn't show up in the list of packages under 'Preferences > Project Interpreter', and PyCharm isn't able to autocomplete anything involving packages.

But when I run the same script from the command line, it works just fine.

Any ideas on why the same conda env in PyCharm can't see the packages installed by pip?

In terminal pip list:

[image: in terminal pip list]

In pycharm package list:

[image: in pycharm package list]

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm 2017.1:

- Click on the button next to the `Project Interpreter` name (a gear icon) and choose `Add Local`
- Choose the path to your conda env (probably `~/anaconda/envs/your-env-name/bin/python`)

You should see the table with a list of packages in the `Preferences` window below the `Project Interpreter` name.